# Twitter Issue : Rate limit exceeded

Tags: api, twitter

I am using Twitter's API for finding location / place of Tweets.I am using Twitters Status/Show/:Id

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/205935129938497537.json

which gives me location of Tweet by Tweet Id.

however i am getting '`Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour`' Error.

Does anyone know the solution for this? I had searched it on Google but it says pasing access_token to url will exceed requests to 350 Only. I want more requests.

Or does anybody has better solution / alternative way of finding place /location of Twitters Tweers?

Comment: Facing the same problem right now as I am trying to unfollow a number of people on Twitter. This is very frustrating